# Assigning multi dimensional array element in simple way

Tags: javascript

I want to quickly assign like this:

```
obj = {};
obj["train-11456"]["2016-12-11" ]["chair car"] = 'waitlisted';
```

All those elements are objects.

We can do this in PHP and it creates them all automatically.

**What is the simplest way to assign like this?**

Longer way is:

```
obj["train-11456"] = {}  //only if this key does not already exist
obj["train-11456"]["2016-12-11" ] = {}; //only if this key does not alreadu exist
obj["train-11456"]["2016-12-11" ]["chair car"] = 'waitlisted';
```

Comment: You can't do that directly in javascript as arrays (which is what the [] brackets represent) can only have numeric indexes. This is an OO language (ish) so you have to deal with objects.

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this

```
obj = {
    "train-11456": {
        "2016-12-11": {
            "chair car" : "waitlisted"
        }
    }
};
```

OR

```
obj = {"train-11456":{"2016-12-11":{"chair car":"waitlisted"}}};
```

Comment: obj["train-11456"]["2016-12-11" ]["chair car"] The difference i feel is, the curly braces instead of square brackets and closed at the end instead of immediate. The number of curly brackets and square brackets are same if you see.

Comment: also it  discards earlier object data. Of little use.

Comment: If you already defined obj["train-11456"]["2016-12-11" ], then you are free to use obj["train-11456"]["2016-12-11" ]["chair car"] = 'waitlisted'; without any issues

Answer (score 2):

Well there is no straight way to do this. But you can write a utility function to do it for you. Its kind of shorthand

```
function objUtil (obj) {
    var _o = obj || {};

    return function () {
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 0),
            val = args.splice(args.length - 1, 1)[0],
            res = {},
            index, length, key, objPointer, lastObjPtr;

        objPointer = _o;

        for (index = 0, length = args.length; index < length; index ++) {
            key = args[index];
            lastObjPtr = objPointer;
            objPointer = objPointer[key] = {};
        }

        lastObjPtr[key] = val;
        return _o;
    }
}
```

And then call it like

```
var obj,
   populateObj = objUtil(obj={});

populateObj('train-11456', '2016-12-11', 'chair car', 'waitlisted');
console.log(obj);
```